# Prolog findall help

Tags: prolog

So i have a database of train stations simply labelled train(st1, st4). etc

I want to implement a find all predicate so that a user could query allpaths(X,Y, Paths). 
And the code would return all paths from X to Y.

Any help would be awesome thanks

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do you have a predicate for a single path "path(X, Y, Path)"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog findall/3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082855/prolog-findall-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
train(st1,st4).
train(st1,st2).
train(st2,st3).
train(st3,st4).
train(st4,st5).
train(st3,st6).
train(st6,st5).
find(X,Y,[X|Y]):-train(X,Y).
find(X,Y,[X|Q]):-train(X,Z),find(Z,Y,Q).
findall2(X,Y):-find(X,Y,Q),write(Q),nl,fail.
```

I hope it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as @sowa, but with the last line changed to:

```
allpaths(X, Y, Ps) :- findall(P, find(X, Y, P), Ps).
```

`findall/3` is a built-in Prolog predicate.