# Prolog findall/3

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, prolog-findall

Say I have a predicate pred containing several facts.

```
pred(a, b, c).
pred(a, d, f).
pred(x, y, z).
```

Can I use findall/3 to get a list of all facts which can be pattern matched?

for example, if I have

`pred(a, _, _)`
I would like to obtain

`[pred(a, b, c), pred(a, d, f)]`

Comment: You mean like this? `findall( p(a, X, Y), pred(a, X, Y), L).`? I'm probably oversimplifying what you're asking...

Comment: @mbratch this will result in something of the form `[pred(a, _801, _802), pred(a, _901, _902)]`, so with unbounded variables

Comment: When I run `findall( p(a, X, Y), pred(a, X, Y), L).` with swipl I get `[p(a,b,c), p(a,d,f)]`. Did you try it? Exactly what are you wanting to supply for inputs? I'm not sure if sicstus-prolog behavior of `findall` may be a little different.

Comment: Note that if you run it with underscores, like `findall(p(a,_,_), pred(a,_,_), L).` you'll see the results you mentioned since those are anonymous variables and can't be instantiated. I can reproduce your result running it that way. You need the `X` and `Y` in place to get instantiation.

Comment: I neglected to mention, you can use the same functor as your fact, so this also works: `findall(pred(a,X,Y), pred(a,X,Y), L).`.

Answer (score 1):

Just summing up what @mbratch said in the comment section:

Yes, but you have to make sure that you either use *named* variables or construct a simple helper predicate that does that for you:

Named variables:

```
findall(pred(a,X,Y),pred(a,X,Y),List).
```

Helper predicate:

```
special_findall(X,List):-findall(X,X,List).

?-special_findall(pred(a,_,_),List).
List = [pred(a, b, c), pred(a, d, f)].
```

Note that this **doesn't** work:

```
findall(pred(a,_,_),pred(a,_,_),List).
```

Because it is equivalent to

```
 findall(pred(a,A,B),pred(a,C,D),List).
```

And thus doesn't unify the Variables of `Template` with those of `Goal`.