# Quadratic equation solving in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have wrote a code to solve equation with like terms (eg:- x^2+5*x+6=0). Here 'x' has two values. I can take two values by entering ';'. But I need to get the all possible answers when I run the program at once. Is it possible in prolog?

Comment: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3

Comment: I used findall/3 and it works. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog findall/3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082855/prolog-findall-3)

Answer (score 3):

Well for a quadratic equation, if the discriminant is zero, then
there is only one solution, so you can directly compute one or two 
solutions, and return them in a list.

[image]

The discriminat is the expression under the square root. So the 
classical prolog code for a real number solution reads as follows:

```
solve(A*_^2+B*_+C=0,L) :- D is B^2-4*A*C,
   (D < 0 -> L = [];
    D =:= 0 -> X is (-B)/(2*A), L = [X];
    S is sqrt(D), X1 is (-B-S)/(2*A), 
      X2 is (-B+S)/(2*A), L=[X1,X2]).
```

Here is an example run:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.0)

?- solve(1*x^2+5*x+6=0,L).
L = [-3.0, -2.0].
```